# Comparing a field in the current record with another field in the previous record of database table using c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have the follwoing situation. Appartment rent payment collection table. I call it rentTransactions. In this table I have 4 fields. appartmentNumber, ammountPaid, startDate, endDate.

If we assume that we have two transctions in this table.

If the startDate of the second transactiin is higher by x number of days than the end date of the first transaction that could mean (Assuming data accuracy)

1- the appartment was vacunt for x number of days. 
2-the tenent did not pay for x number of days

The appartment building is for long term lease and the turnover (tenent change) is very low. So we can eleminate the first possibilty for the time being.

So how can I use LINQ to subtract the end date of the previous record from the startDate of the current record.

Then make a new table that I can store in it the appartment number. The end date of the transaction and the number of days the unit is vacant. Number of vacant days can be zero, later I will omitt the zeros out.

One thing to take into consideratiin is that the last record in appartment1 for example will be followed by the first record of the second appartment and we should not do any subtractiins for reords belonging to different appartments.

I appreciate any help or pointing me in the right path

Best regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690856/linq-query-compare-to-record-before?rq=1

See if that doesn't address your issue

Comment: Simply order by date so you have an array.  Then join length - 2 and length - 1 (or last item)

Comment: It would be difficult to help without any code to go on, but assuming you can write the code and are just looking for the idea, you could `GroupBy` apparmentNumber, followed by `OrderBy` endDate, and then a simple `(endDate - startDate).TotalDays` will give you what you need. Of course, there are more steps in the middle, such as checking for empty set, etc.